# Pandas - moving data between columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df1
Reference_Code   Last_Price   Price_Now
B0002EH2X2       NaN          9.99
B0075DRIAK       NaN          19.99
B0083F2XDQ       NaN          29.99
B009AS5VW0       NaN          39.99

df2
Reference_Code   Price_Now
B0002EH2X2       49.99
B0075DRIAK       19.99
B0083F2XDQ       29.99
B009AS5VW0       9.99
```

I would like to move the values from the Price_Now in df1 into the Last_Price column in df1, where the price is difference to df2. In the example above, I would expect the output to be;

```
df1
Reference_Code   Last_Price   Price_Now
B0002EH2X2       9.99         49.99
B0075DRIAK       NaN          19.99
B0083F2XDQ       NaN          29.99
B009AS5VW0       39.99        9.99
```

I am trying to use pandas, but have myself in a bit of a spin. The dataset is much larger than the tables shown above

Answer (score 0):

Do a map:

```
s = df1['Reference_Code'].map(df2.set_index('Reference_Code')['Price_Now'])
mask = (s!=df1['Price_Now'])
df1['Last_Price'] = df1['Price_Now'].where(mask)
df1['Price_Now'] =  s.where(mask, df['Price_Now']
```

Output:

```
  Reference_Code  Last_Price  Price_Now
0     B0002EH2X2        9.99      49.99
1     B0075DRIAK         NaN      19.99
2     B0083F2XDQ         NaN      29.99
3     B009AS5VW0       39.99       9.99
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This doesn't quite do what I need. It maps the price_now from df2 into the last_price field, but only when the items are nan. I want to move the price_now from df1 into last_price and then update the price_now with the price_now from df2. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @in_d sorry, i didn't read it carefully. Updated.

Comment: thanks!  I really appreciate it!!